# Десериализация json в объект c# с protected сеттерами

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

Пишу на asp.net core 3.1, проект web API есть класс

```
public SomeClass
{
  public int A {get; protected set;}
  public string B {get; protected set;}
  public SomeClass(int a, string b){
    A = a;
    B = b;
  }
  public SomeClass(){}
}
```

Есть контроллер

```
public SomeController : Controller
{
  [HttpPut]
  public SomeMethod([FromForm] SomeClass someObject){
  ...
  }
}
```

В someObject все свойства приходят null

Comment: почему не сделать их публичными?

Comment: Какой сериализатор вы используете?

Comment: Для таких дел лучше и проще использовать poco объекты с публичными полями.

Comment: [Вот решение](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25950112/json-deserialize-to-constructed-protected-setter-array) для `Newtonsoft.Json`

Comment: А [решение](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/30688) для `System.Text.Json` кажется подъедет только в .NET 5

Comment: сериализатор встроенный использовали, но потом перешли на Newtonsoft, публичными решили не делать, чтобы из других частей кода (например на фронте) нельзя было что-то менять

Comment: Использование  [JsonProperty] не помогло.
Теперь при использовании protected конструктора не удается создать объект, если сделать публичный пустой конструктор, то проблема с приходящими null свойствами остается, от протектед сеттеров отказаться не можем

Comment: текст ошибки при попытке десериализации с протектед конструктором 
`System.InvalidOperationException: Could not create an instance of type 'SetGotToTheSceneDto'. Model bound complex types must not be abstract or value types and must have a parameterless constructor. Alternatively, give the 'setGotToTheSceneDto' parameter a non-null default value.
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Binders.ComplexTypeModelBinder.CreateModel(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)`

Comment: @EgorMalyshkin, по ссылкам есть пример с `[JsonConstructor]`

Comment: @Grundy пробовал добавлять его к протектед конструктору - ошибка не исчезла

Comment: его не к протектеду надо добавлять а к публичному. В примере у тебя вполне себе public конструктор

Comment: если использовать протектед конструктор пустой + параметрический публичный, то ошибка, если использовать публичный пустой + публичный параметрический, то поля приходят null или 0

Comment: @EgorMalyshkin, непонятно как ты их используешь, и судя по твоим результатам - используешь неправильно

Comment: `[JsonConstructor]
protected SomeClass(){}
public SomeClass(int  a,string  b){...}`
или 
`[JsonConstructor]
public  SomeClass(){}
public  SomeClass(int a,string b){...}`

Comment: @EgorMalyshkin, ты ставишь атрибут не на тот конструктор просто. При его использовании тебе не нужен конструктор без параметров

Comment: пробовал ставить наоборот - не помогло

Comment: покажи как пробовал.

Comment: `protected SomeClass(){} [JsonConstructor]  public SomeClass(int  a,string  b){...} `или  `public  SomeClass(){} [JsonConstructor] public  SomeClass(int a,string b){...}`

Comment: во втором случае все точно работает.

Comment: все свойства приходят либо null, либо дефолтные  значения

Comment: @EgorMalyshkin, значит ты что-то не договариваешь :-) Либо у тебя какой-то другой код, либо ты что-то неправильное шлешь, либо неправильно проверяешь

Comment: там разве что дто не такая простая, а так все сказал. Отправлять пробовал через сваггер и через постман,с формой особо не ошибешься

Comment: сейчас поймал такую же проблему при [FromQuery] в get методе

Comment: Мда :-) похоже все проще. Все решения нацелены на то, что придет json, соответственно должен прийти application/json тип и в этом случае в форме ничего не будет. А так как сейчас используется форма, то не используется json биндер, который как раз и должен был пользоваться атрибутами. То есть в данном случае решением может стать написание своего биндера для класса